# Pull Dependency version from Spring-dependency-management plugin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, dependency-management

I have a `Gradle Task` to pull the dependencies from a project and play with that data. Below is my `Gradle Task`

```
task gavValidation() {

    doLast {
        project(':app').configurations.each { 
            configurationType ->
            println "configurationType >>> "+configurationType.name
            configurationType.allDependencies.each {
                gav ->
                println gav.group+" : "+gav.name+" : "+gav.version
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The `print` statement always come as `null` when it is printing `gav.version` above.

What i found is that, the versions of these dependencies are maintained in `Spring Dependency Management` Plugin. Below is the snippet

```
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Edgware.RELEASE'
            mavenBom 'io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-dependencies:1.5.0.RELEASE'
            mavenBom 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.5.13.RELEASE'

        }
        dependencies {
            dependency 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.8.0'
            dependency 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.8.0'

        }
    }
```

How to get the version in my custom-task ? that is currently coming as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [Working with Dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_dependencies.html) , the methods `Configuration.getDependencies()` or `Configuration.getAllDependencies()` only return the declared dependencies and do not trigger dependency resolution. So for dependencies coming from Spring BOM, the version is not known yet.

You can use `Configuration.getResolvedConfiguration()` method instead, as follows:

```
task gavValidation() {
    doLast {
        configurations.each { configurationType ->
            println " ***************** configurationType >>> " + configurationType.name
            if (configurationType.canBeResolved) {
                configurationType.getResolvedConfiguration().getResolvedArtifacts().each { artefact ->
                    ModuleVersionIdentifier id = artefact.getModuleVersion().getId()
                    println id.group + " : " + id.name + " : " + id.version
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic !! Thanks